How to build HTML files from a storybook project?
I created a storybook project via npx storybook@latest init and chose html as the type and html-vite as the bundler. I want to use storybook to distribute the templates to different production apps like outlined in this article: https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/design-systems-for-developers/react/en/distribute/
Now after the initial storybook setup was done I discovered the actual templates to be js files. I understand that this goes well with the technology because the stories themselves are js files but in the end I want to distribute plain HTML templates to projects that don't use any js frontend framework.
I didn't find any, but is there any command I can use or what does html-vite actually do at all? What additional steps do I need to take in order to build html templates?
